# How to implement background music to ur jump n run game with levels

Tags: javascript, audio, background, game-development

I need to do a project for my IT course in school. I implemented a Jump N Run Game in Visual Studio Code with Javascript. It has 4 levels and works with html. My teacher now said that I have to add background music. And I have no idea where to start . I'm really not that good in IT and therefore I don't really know what information is needed in order to help me out with that question. I could send my whole folder in if needed. Thank you in advance.
P.S.: I need to be finished by the end of the week.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in JavaScript fairly easily.

```js
// Create a variable to reference your music file
// that is stored in a new Audio object
const music = new Audio("./pathToMusicFile.wav");

// Add an event listener to detect user interaction
// and add a callback function that will run when
// the event occurs. I've added it to the window
// here, but you could add the event to the button
// that starts your game. I've named the callback
// function playMusic here
   window.addEventListener("click", playMusic);

// Function to play the music
// in a continuous loop
function playMusic() {
  // start the music
  music.play();
  // make the music loop continuously
  music.loop = true;
}

  // Note: If you want to stop the music at some point
  // you can do it like this: music.stop()
  // which you might want to do when each level of your
  // game ends, and  then perhaps, play a different tune
  // for the next level
```

This should be enough to get you started, I hope it helps